# Avoid MessageBox while closing child window

Tags: visual-c++, mfc, mdichild

I am having a child window derived from `CFormView`.  On certain condition in `OnCreate()` function, I want to close this window.

I tried 2 options:

```
int CFilterWindow::OnCreate(LPCREATESTRUCT lpCreateStruct)
{
    if (CFormView::OnCreate(lpCreateStruct) == -1)
    return -1;

//Trial-1
if (!IsInitialized())
{
    DestroyWindow();
    return 0;
}
//Trial-2
if (!IsInitialized())
{
    return -1;
}

return 0;
}
```

In both scenarios, the window is closed but my system returns `"Failed to create empty document."`

How do I avoid this message?

Comment: Use Debug + Break All and look at the Call Stack debugger window to see how you got there.  It is a doc/view programming flaw in your code.  You created a document but then when MFC tried to create the view for it you said "you can't look at it".  You should have stopped this sooner, not permitting the document to be created first.

Comment: Can u tell me what should be expected then? I created document, then I am creating view but closing same view within OnCreate() function due to certain condition.

Answer (score 0):

This is a completely normal behavior.

Document, Frame and View are created in one turn. First the document is created, than the frame and than the inner view. If one of the operations failed all other are also rolled back and fail.

So in the case of the MDI OnFileNew calls OpenDocumentFile from you template.
This function creates the new CDocument, followed by a new frame window.  The frame window creates the view. This fails due to your code.

Your error message comes from CMultiDocTemplate::OpenDocumentFile because CreateNewFrame fails.

Let the MFC create your window and destroy the view it in OnInitialUpdate. This should work without this message.

Comment: I got a crash after doing same in OnIniialUpdate function. Crash is in void CFrameWnd::InitialUpdateFrame(CDocument* pDoc, BOOL bMakeVisible) function which trigerrs a message WM_INITIALUPDATE for InInitialUpdate and later calls OnActivateFrame() function. I think by the time I destroy window, it tries to do some operation on view pointer which is garbage after DestroyWindow().

Comment: I tried working with CloseWindow() and WM_DESTROY messsage as well but same result...crash

Comment: Than I see no other chance than posting a private WM_APP message to your view. When you receive ist use DestroyWindw. Never post or send WM_DESTROY as a message. It is internal.